# Why didn't the king of Gondor return earlier?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Something in the accepted answer of [Who knew of Aragorn's true lineage prior to his revealing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/139690/who-knew-of-aragorns-true-lineage-prior-to-his-revealing) which I asked struck me as odd.

According to the accepted answer, Elrond in the books introduced Aragorn to Boromir as such:

> 'And who are you, and what have you to do with Minas Tirith?' asked Boromir, looking in wonder at the lean face of the Ranger and his weather-stained cloak.
> 'He is Aragorn son of Arathorn,' said Elrond; 'and he is descended through many fathers from Isildur Elendil's son of Minas Ithil.

And so the lost line of kings is probably revealed officially to one who is groomed to be the future Steward of Gondor (ignoring the likelihood that Denethor already figured it out but kept it to himself). The movies, however, phrased it differently:

> Legolas: This is no mere ranger. He is Aragorn, son of Arathorn. You owe him your allegiance.
> Boromir: Aragorn? This is Isildur's heir?

There appears to be an important difference here. Boromir, who is being groomed for Stewardship, apparently recognises the line of kings by name without even hearing the name Elendil. He didn't even need to question Legolas on why he owes Aragorn his allegiance - he just knew he does indeed owe it to whoever bears the name "Aragorn son of Arathorn". Does this imply that the Ruling Stewards knew where the legitimate heir to the kingship of Gondor is all this time?

That's my first question, which is more relevant to the cinematic version. Continuing with questions about the books, since it's unlikely to be covered in the movies:

- Why didn't the surviving heirs of Elendil return to Gondor earlier?
- Regardless of when the Ruling Stewards identified a true heir, why didn't they move forth to bring him back?

Comment: One of your sub-questions is answered by http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73172/why-didnt-isildurs-heir-come-forward-sooner

Comment: I always assumed he put two and two together based on the name prefixes.

Comment: I'd assumed that in the movie Boromir was cued in by "You owe him your allegiance". That can only be the heirs of Isildur.

Answer (score 16):

### Did the Ruling Stewards of Gondor know where the Heir of Isildur was?

From the point of view of the books, there is no evidence to suggest that the Stewards had any idea that the Heirs of Isildur were alive or where they were. This seems to be supported by the confusion that Faramir/Boromir's dream gave them and the need to seek Elrond to solve it.

> Seek for the Sword that was Broken,
>
> In Imladris it dwells….
> <sub>Fellowship of the Ring, Book 2</sub>

Furthermore, in Appendix A, it states that there were rumours of heirs in the North, but the stewards seemingly ignored those rumours.

> ...some remembered the ancient line of the North, which it was rumoured still lived on in the shadows. But against such thoughts the Ruling Stewards hardened their hearts...
> <sub>Return of the King, Book 7: Appendix A</sub>

The films seem to suggest otherwise. From the line in the question, we seem to be led to believe that the Stewards of Gondor have a record of the heirs of Isildur, and that the current heir is named Aragorn, son of Arathorn. To what purpose this change has been made is unclear.

### Why didn't the Ruling Stewards move forward to bring back the Heir.

From the books, they had no interest in doing so. Denethor was not the vain, bitter mad-man that the films portray him as, his rejection of an "Heir"'s claim was not of jealousy or pride, as is suggested by his humility in accepting that the line of Stewards will always remain Stewards:

> "How many hundreds of years needs it to make a steward a king, if the king returns not? " he asked. "Few years, maybe, in other places of less royalty," my father answered. **"In Gondor ten thousand years would not suffice."**

Regardless of his humility, Denethor would have rejected any claim to the throne, as would any other Steward, most likely:

> So! With the left hand thou wouldst use me for a little while as a shield against Mordor, and with the right bring up this Ranger of the North to supplant me.
> But I say to thee, Gandalf Mithrandir, I will not be thy tool! ‘I am Steward of the House of Anárion. I will not step down to be the dotard chamberlain of an upstart. **Even were his claim proved to me, still he comes but of the line of Isildur.** I will not bow to such a one, last of a ragged house long bereft of lordship and dignity.’

Denethor clearly sees no value in the Rangers of the North and raising them up to the rights of a king. This was seen earlier in the histories of Gondor and Arnor when the line of the Kings of Gondor ended with Ondoher, at this time, however, the claim was rejected because of different laws of ascension between Gondor and Arnor and the way laws practised in Númenor.

> The claim was rejected. In this Pelendur, the Steward of King Ondoher, played the chief part.
>
> 'The Council of Gondor answered: **"The crown and royalty of Gondor belongs solely to the heirs of Meneldil, son of Anárion, to whom Isildur relinquished this realm. In Gondor this heritage is reckoned through the sons only**; and we have not heard that the law is otherwise in Arnor."...
>
> ...'"Moreover, in Númenor of old the sceptre descended to the eldest child of the king, whether man or woman. It is true that the law has not been observed in the lands of exile ever troubled by war.
> <sub>Return of the King, Book 7: Appendix A</sub>

The Ruling Stewards therefore both had no interest in rediscovering their King, didn't know if an heir existed and they didn't believe the line of Isildur were the rightful heirs, only the line of Anarion.

### Why didn't the surviving heirs of Elendil return to Gondor earlier.

This is a bit of a confusing one, so I'll start with a little bit on the lines and then move down to why Aragorn was successful and why no one else really tried.

First things first. Elendil was High King of Gondor and Arnor after the fall of Númenor. After his death, his first son, Isildur was the heir of the High kingship and had all rights to the throne. However, Isildur was killed as he was returning to Arnor from Gondor, after committing rule of Gondor to Meneldir, son of Isildur's brother Anárion. After Isildur's death in the Gladden fields, Meneldir had assumed the Kingship of Gondor (while the Kingship of Arnor had gone to Isildur's fourth and last son, Valandil). It was henceforth that the rule was split between Gondor and Arnor, and from which the Stewards of Gondor claim the line of Gondorian kings comes from Anárion, who's line ended with Ondoher and his sons. The kingship of Gondor moved to Ondoher's (descendent) second cousin once removed, Eärnil II (Clear chart of relationship can be seen [here](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Ondoher#Genealogy))

Onto the first King of Arnor reclaiming the throne of Gondor. This occurred after the death of Onodher and his sons. Arvedui went to Gondor claiming the kingship as not only a descendent of Isildur, the rightful High King of Arnor and Gondor, but also as the husband of Fíriel, the rightful queen of Gondor according to the Numenorean laws of Ascension (detailed above). Arvedui's claim was rejected by a council of Gondor, by persuasion of the Steward Pelendur. Eärnil II was the raised to Kingship, however the line of Kings would end with his son, Eärnur in TA 2050, after defeating Angmar.

After Arvedui's attempts, he would go on to rule Arnor after his father's death, he would however be the Last King of Arnor as they were utterly defeated by the Witch-king and his armies our of Angmar. The people of Arnor would be scattered, wandering people, with Arvedui's sons taking the title of *Chieftain of the Dúnedain*. The Chieftains of the sunken house, after their fall from grace continued to live in Arnor, however the peoples of the Dúnedain were small and scattered and never rose again to the power of old, before the time of Aragorn Elessar.

Onto Aragorn's claim. Aragorn himself never claimed the Kingship of Gondor, he himself unfurled the standard of Elendil and rode forth into the Battle of the Plennor bearing it, however he would remain outside of the gates, furling his banner and naming Imrahil temporary Lord of the City. It was in disguise that he entered the city and the Houses of Healing, and healed Merry, Éowyn and Farmir, in accordance with the prophecy: *“The hands of the king are the hands of a healer, and so shall the rightful king be known”*. Aragorn then left the city, hooded and cloaked, and yet the people of Minas Tirith followed him, for they had heard rumours. However, the next morning they only saw the banner of Dol Amroth and wondered if the Return of the King had been but a dream.

It was only after returning from the Battle of the Morannon and the destruction of the Ring and Sauron that Aragorn was crowned outside the gates of the city, and the people had all accepted him, he had not set forth to claim the city from them.

> Then Faramir stood up and spoke in a clear voice: ’Men of Gondor hear now the Steward of this Realm! Behold! one has come to claim the kingship again at last. Here is Aragorn son of Arathorn, chieftain of the Dúnedain of Arnor, Captain of the Host of the West, bearer of the Star of the North, wielder of the Sword Reforged, victorious in battle, whose hands bring healing, the Elfstone, Elessar of the line of Valandil, Isildur’s son, Elendil’s son of Númenor. Shall he be king and enter into the City and dwell there?’
> And all the host and all the people cried "yea" with one voice.
> <sub>Return of the King: Book 6, Chapter V, The Steward and the King</sub>

Comment: By itself I would not read "In Gondor ten thousand years would not suffice." as personal humility, it can as well be a statement of how the culture in Gondor would not allow him to claim kingship, i.e. he might say with this that he would have an uprising at his hands should he simply proclaim himself the new king.

Answer (score 4):

You can read in Appendix A of Arvedui's attempt to claim the throne of Gondor after the death of Ondoher. The claim was rejected, primarily because Arvedui was not descended from Meneldil son of Anárion. After Arvedui's death, there was no northern kingdom to speak of, so his descendents (despite having some descent from Anárion via Arvedui's wife Fíriel daughter of Ondoher) had even less of a power base from which to claim the throne. Gondor eventually seated Eärnil, second cousin once removed of Ondoher, on the throne, but the throne was left vacant after he died without an heir.

Aragorn, on the other hand, had one key thing in his favor: he was the victorious general who led the armies of Gondor against Sauron after the death of Denethor, and so was very popular among the people. Although he had a legitimate claim to the throne, he was acclaimed King by the lords and people of Gondor rather than having to forcibly claim the throne.

Comment: Earnil had a son, Earnur.  It was Earnur who was the last king of Gondor pre-Aragorn, riding off to accept the Witch-King's challenge, with no heir of his own.

Comment: I vaguely recall rewriting this answer repeatedly to try to keep it brief; I think I shortened it too much by conflating Eärnil and Eärnur

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the similar question being referenced, part of the concealment was, perhaps, trying to protect the rest of the bloodlines from extinction via enemies.

Also, though, Stewards ruled as kings, very proud kings, at that. Though the Rangers of the North were of the same royal bloodline, remember that, between Elendil's sons, the King of Gondor was Anarion, as Isildur went north to rule Arnor.  The men of Gondor and the family of the Stewards considered the men of the north as a somewhat inferior wilderness rabble, whose kingdom was wiped out under the rule of Isidur's heirs. Even if they were duty bound to hand over the throne, if it came to it, I doubt they'd feel inclined to go to any effort to make that happen, on their own initiative.

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in *The Return of the King*'s Appendix A.

A combination of factors answer this:

1. The descendants of the kings were few

   - Reduced by Kin-strife
   - Fled to Umbar
   - Taken non-Númenórean wives
2. Descendants not of "pure-blood"
3. Not all would allow their claim

> Now the descendants of the kings had become few. Their numbers had been greatly diminished in the Kin-strife; whereas since that time the kings had become jealous and watchful of those near akin. Often those on whom suspicion fell had fled to Umbar and there joined the rebels; while others had renounced their lineage and taken wives not of Númenórean blood.
>
> So it was that no claimant to the crown could be found who was of pure blood, or whose claim all would allow; and all feared the memory of the Kin-strife, knowing that if any such dissension arose again, then Gondor would perish. Therefore, though the years lengthened, the Steward continued to rule Gondor, and the crown of Elendil lay in the lap of King Eärnil in the Houses of the Dead, where Eärnur had left it.

Answer (score 0):

Elrond's answer in the books is quite specific: he reveals Aragon's bloodline, not that he is Isildur's heir. This suggests two possibilities: Aragorn is descended from a king's younger brother at some point and Elrond either knows, or at least is not certain, that there exists someone with a better claim. Alternatively, Aragorn could be from an illegitimate line. In either case Aragon's line would not behave been in a position to claim the throne. Ultimately bloodline plus Aragorn's actions lead to inheritance anyway.
Of course the film is simply trying to paraphrase the books for reasons of space.
Caveat: someone else may know of a line in the books confirming Aragorn as the legitimate heir. I haven't been able to go through and check.

Comment: Stuart Hall - didn't  you read the appendixes?  They show that the kingship of Anor, the Kingship of Arthedain, and then the chieftainship of the Dunedain of Eriador always passed from father to son to grandson to great grandson to great great grandson and so on generation after generation all through the Third Age. They also say  Aragorn was the rightful heir of Isildur.  They say that Aragorn's parents were married but do not say whether earlier heirs  of Isildur were married.  So either all Isildur's heirs were married or else legitimate birth was not a requirement.